# Can I duplicate magazines other than S.P.E.C.I.A.L. to gain skills?

Tags: fallout-4

Can I use duplicate glitch to duplicate magazines such as U.S. Covert Operation Manual or Astoundingly Awesome Tales to stack the skills or advantage? Like SPECIAL magazine, every duplicated item is new/unread. Can I dupe other types of magazine?

Comment: What other magazines do seems to be the equivalent of addPerk command, which does not allow multiple instances of the same perk to stack bonuses. I'll leave answering to someone who can test that however. It could be helpful if you added a reference to how the glitch works.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot duplicate magazines to gain perks from them. Unlike the 'You're Special' book, as Deltharis mentioned in the comments, the magazines actually give you an instance of a perk, or unlock tattoos/hairstyles/settlement items.

There would be no reason to duplicate tattoos/hairstyles/settlement items magazines, as finding them unlocks the reward, and there's no use in unlocking them again. Some of the other magazines, such as the Wasteland Survivor's Guide and Amazingly Awesome Tales, each give a unique perk with only one rank (e.g. Wasteland Survival 1, Wasteland Survival 2, and so on).

The remaining magazines (Grognak the Barbarian, Massachusetts Surgical Journal, Tales of a Junktown Jerky Vendor, Tesla Science, Tumblers Today, U.S. Covert Operations Manual, Unstoppables) have multi-point perks, where each magazine gives one point into that perk. However, magazine duplication does not give multiple points into the respective perk. Each magazine needs to be found to max out the respective perk ([Example of user describing no bonus effects from duplicating perk magazines and bobbleheads](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/72867971#9)).

There is actually a case of the same magazine being obtainable in the game twice, without item duplication. Grognak the Barbarian issue #05 is obtainable in both Vault 75 and Vault 81. I obtained both #05 issues before finding all 10 issues of Grognak, but only received a point in the Barbarian perk for the first one I found. To get the Barbarian perk maxed at 10 points, I had to find all 10 issues of the magazine.

Answer (score 2):

I did duplicate the magazines but there is no effect. I think both the book and magazines are programed differently. I wanted to stack the tesla for the 10% extra in core duration but to no avail. It doesn't happen the same as with the book. Dogmeat got a new one, but can be seen on his mout, so I guess it is possible to duplicate them but there is no effect other than having multiple copies.